# Unable to include external previous built .a libraries in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a libgarithm.a library previously compiled  and have a header file garith.h  how could i import it in my cmake project . I have included header files from 
include_directories("/home/gaurav/Desktop/garith-lib/include") 
but unable to link libraries and it is giving a comile time error 
--- undefined reference to `multi(int, int)' the function in my library

Answer (score 2):

You should create an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) for your library and then use `target_link_libraries`:

```
add_library(garithm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET garithm PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /path/to/libgarithm.a
)
set_property(TARGET garithm PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    /home/gaurav/Desktop/garith-lib/include
)

...

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo garithm)
```

Include directories are declared on the imported target as well so you don't have to call `include_directories`

**EDIT:** `target_include_directories`doesn't work with imported targets, set the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` instead

Comment: Thank You Very much But now I am getting Error --: Error:Cannot specify include directories for imported target "garithm".

Comment: I edited my answer. Are you using `target_include_directories` or are you setting the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with CMake 3.12.1, target_include_directories as well as other syntactic sugar for normal targets is also supported with imported targets.

For those writing cmake files with these statements, please do add `cmake_minimum_required(3.12)`

If you are getting errors such when compiling a particular third party library, check the `cmake --version`